# Issue with formating element of list on 2 places

Tags: python, list, format, element

I'm trying to format my data on 2 places. If it contains only 1 element, it should append 0 to it. For example `new_time = [10,52]`My desire output is [10,52`]` For [10,5] My desire output is [10,05] I read about this method `new_time = [new_time[0],new_time[1]:02]`. But output of this is invalid syntax. Does anybody know why it isn't work? I did similar exercise and it works.

Comment: Please show an example of the code you're using and the output you get.

Comment: Your issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for integers to be denoted with leading zeroes, and it is by design.
Try to run this statement into your python console:  `print(05)`. You would get an error stating that

```
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; 
use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

But you can typecast integers into strings and logically put leading zeroes if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Integers(and Floats) can not be written with leading zeros. What you can do in this case is to convert them to string like this:

```
new_time = [10,5]
ls= [f'{_:02}' for _ in new_time]
print(ls) # Returns ['10', '05']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can not display left-zeros for values of type `int`, unless you change them into `str`:

```
new_time = ["%02d"%i for i in new_time]
```

for which, `new_time` outputs:

```
['10', '05']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  new_time = [10, 5]
  formated_time = []
  for item in new_time:
  if item < 10:
     time = f"0{item}"
     formated_time.append(time)
  if item >= 10:
     time = item
     formated_time.append(time)
  print(formated_time)
  """note:but while using it again you should use type('int') before the item"""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).